# Can Lord Shiva give positions of all Gods including the position of Vishnu and Brahma?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puranas, shloka, reference

I want some verses where it's said that Lord Shiva can grant the post of Brahma, Vishnu and Indra and other gods to his devotees. Give verses with exact locations from shashtras.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, Lord Shiva can grant the position of any Gods be it Brahma, Vishnu or Indra to his devotees if he is pleased.

### [image]

> ### From Mahabharata :
>
> > **ब्रह्मत्वं केशवत्वं वा शक्रत्वं वा सुरैः सह ॥  त्रैलोक्यम्याधिपत्यं वा
> > तुष्टो रुद्रः प्रयच्छति ।**
> >
> > ~ Mahābhārat — Anūśāsan Parva- Chapter —18 , Verse-64
> >
> > If Rudra be gratified with a person, **he can confer upon him the states
> > of ether Brahmā or of Narayana or of Sakra(Indra) with all the deities under
> > him**, or the sovereignty of the three worlds.
>
> ---
>
> ### From Liṅga Mahāpurāṅam :
>
> > ṣṇ     
> > ā      
> >     Ś-
> >
> > कोहं ब्रह्माथवा देवा दैत्या देवारिसूदनाः । मुनयश्च महात्मनः प्रसादेन
> > विना प्रभोः ॥ यः सप्तविंशको नित्यः परात्परतरः प्रभुः । विश्वामरेश्वरो
> > वंद्यो विश्वाधारोमहेश्वरः ॥ स एव सर्वदेवेशः सर्वेषामपि शङ्करः ।  लीलया
> > देवदैत्येंद्रविभागमकरोद्धरः ॥ **तस्यांशमेकं संपूज्य देवा देवत्वमागताः ।
> > ब्रह्मा ब्रह्मत्वमापन्नो ह्यहं विष्णुत्वमेव च ॥ तमपूज्य जगत्यस्मिन् कः
> > पुमान् सिद्धिमिच्छति ।  तस्मात्तेनैव हंतव्या लिङ्गार्चनविधेर्बलात् ॥**
> >
> > ~ Linga Purana, 1.71.50-54
> >
> > Lord Viṣṇu said : What am I without the grace of Siva? Then who is
> > Brahmā, O gods? Who are the Daityas? Who is the destroyer of the
> > enemies of the gods?
> >
> > And who are the noble souls? Śiva is the lord. He is greater than the
> > greatest. He is eternal. He is comprised of the twenty seven tattvas.
> > He is adorable. He is the lord of eternal beings. He is Maheśvara and
> > the base of the universe.
> >
> > He alone is the lord of gods. It is he who had divided the gods and
> > the asuras.
> >
> > **By adoring his amsa, the gods have achieved to the position of being
> > eternal. Brahma had achieved the position of Brahmahood, while I have
> > attained the position of Vişņu.**
> >
> > Who can achieve success in the world without adoring him? Therefore,
> > by adoring Śiva in the form of a linga in a suitable form, lord Śiva
> > is pleased. The Daityas can be destroyed by him alone.
>
> ---
>
> ### From Suta Samhita(Skand Purāna):
>
> > अस्य प्रसादलेशस्य लवलेशलवेन तु । ईदं विष्णुपदं लब्धम् त्वया नान्येन
> > हेतुना ।।
> >
> > ~ Sūta Saṃhitā ŚivaMahātmya Khaṃḍa —3:14
> >
> > Nandi said to Viṣṇu:
> > **By a smallest part of Śiva's grace you have attained this Viṣṇu**
> > position not otherwise.
>
> ---
>
> ### From Skanda-Māhapurāṇa :
>
> > पूतात्मोवाच । देवदेवमहादेव देवानामभयप्रद । ब्रह्मनारायणेंद्रादि
> > सर्वदेवपदप्रद ॥
> >
> > pūtātmovāca | devadevamahādeva devānāmabhayaprada |
> > brahmanārāyaṇeṃdrādi sarvadevapadaprada ||
> >
> > ~ Skanda Purāṇam — Kaśi Khaṅda,1st section.13:9
> >
> > Putātmā said: 9. O Great lord, O Lord of the Devas, O bestower of
> > freedom from fear unto the Devas, **O bestower of the positions to all
> > the Devas including Brahmā, Nārāyaṇa, Indra and others!**
>
> ---
>
> ### From Parāśar Ūpa Purāṇam :
>
> > पूजया परमा मुक्तिः पूजया शुद्धवेदनम् ११ ब्रह्मविष्ण्वादिदेवानां
> > पदप्राप्तिश्च पूजया अष्टैश्वर्यं सुरत्वं च पदं गान्धर्वपूर्वकम् १२
> > सार्वभौमत्वमीशस्य पूजयैव हि सिद्धयति मनोहराः स्त्रियः सौख्यं
> > कल्याणभवनानि च|| १३
> >
> > ~ Parāśar Ūpa Purāṇam — Chapter-16.11-13
> >
> > Ultimate liberation can be achieved from the Worship of Lord Shiva and
> > **one can even achieve the Post of Brahma, Vishnu and other gods,** and
> > through worship one attains sovereignty.
>
> ---
>
> ### From Shiva Dharma Purana :
>
> > ~ Śiva Dharma Pūrva Purāṇam — Chapter-3, Slokas- 30, 31,32
> >
> > **Viṣṇu attains Viṣṇu Position, Bramhā attains Bramhā Position and Indra
> > attains Indra's Position by doing Śiva Bhakti**
>
> ---
>
> ### From Skanda-Māhapurāṇa :
>
> Pleased by Andhaka's devotion towards the Lotus feet of Shri Rudra,
> Mahadeva became very pleased and he said Andhaka to grant any boon.
> **But Andhaka said he doesn't even want the positions of Brahma, Vishnu or Indra because their position are not eternal they are
> subject of coming and going.** So Andhaka want to be the lord of Ganas
> of Lord Shiva.
>
> > सनत्कुमार उवाच । तस्यैवं स्तुवतो देवः शूलपाणिर्वृषध्वजः । पूर्णे
> > वर्षशतस्यांते प्रीतः प्रोवाच शंकरः ॥ २५ ॥ पुत्र तुष्टोऽस्मि भद्रं ते
> > जातस्त्वं निर्मलोऽधुना । दिव्यं ददामि ते चक्षुः पश्य मां विगतज्वरः ॥
> > २६ ॥ यच्च ते मनसा वापि किंचिच्च कांक्षितं फलम् । तत्तत्सर्वं
> > प्रदास्यामि ब्रूहि दानवसत्तम ॥ २७ ॥
> >
> > Sanatkumāra said:
> > Even as a hundred years elapsed while he was eulogizing thus, Lord Śaṅkara, the trident-bearing Lord, with a bull as his emblem, was
> > pleased and he spoke thus:
> >
> > “Son, welfare unto you. I am pleased with you. Now you have become free from impurities. I shall give you divine vision. Look at
> > me
> > without mental affliction.
> >
> > O excellent Dānava, tell me whatever benefit has been desired mentally by you; I shall grant you.”
> >
> > दानव उवाच । ब्राह्म्यं वैष्णवमेंद्रं वा पदमावृत्तिलक्षणम् । विदितं मम
> > तत्सर्वं मनागपि न कांक्षये ॥ २८ ॥ यदि तुष्टोऽसि देवेश गाणपत्यं ददस्व
> > मे । सविशेषं विशुद्धं च तदक्षय्यं च सर्वदा ॥ २९ ॥
> >
> > **The Dānava said:
> > The position of Brahmā, Viṣṇu or Indra is characterized by coining and going (i.e. impermanence). All this is known to me. I do
> > not
> > desire it at all.**
> >
> > O Lord of Devas, if you are pleased, grant me Gāṇapatya—lordship of the Gaṇas. That is something especially pure and everlasting.
> >
> > ~ Skanda-Māhapurāṇa,  5.1.38.25-29
>
> ---
>
> ### From Shri Shivanand Lahari :
>
> Ādī Śaṅkarāchārya stated this two times in his famous work Śivānanda
> Lahiri so it's not only a stuti but also becomes a Sāśtrīya Pramaṇa as
> it is in accordance with Upanishads, Mahā Purāṇas, Ūpa Purāṇas,
> Itīhāsas:
>
> > त्वमेको लोकानां परमफलदो दिव्यपदवीं वहन्तस्त्वन्मूलां पुनरपि भजन्ते
> > हरिमुखाः । कियद्वा दाक्षिण्यं तव शिव मदाशा च कियती कदा वा मद्रक्षां
> > वहसि करुणापूरितदृशा ॥
> >
> > It means Viṣṇu, Bramhā , Indra all attain their positions by mere
> > grace of Śiva and they always worship Śiva.
> >
> > Śrī śivānanda Laharī ||18
> >
> > करोमि त्वत्पूजां सपदि सुखदो मे भव विभो विधित्वं विष्णुत्वं दिशसि खलु
> > तस्याः फलमिति । पुनश्च त्वां द्रष्टुं दिवि भुवि वहन् पक्षिमृगता
> > मदृष्ट्वा तत्खेदं कथमिह सहे शङ्कर विभो ।।
> >
> > you grant the position of Brahma & Vishnu as a reward for my worship.
> > Then I would have to become a bird and fly in the sky or Become an
> > animal and dig deep in earth.
> >
> > Śrī śivānanda Laharī | 23
>
> ---
>
> ### From Shiva Mahapurana :
>
> > पुण्यातिशयसंयुक्तः सर्वैर्देवैरनुष्ठितः । ब्रह्मणा विष्णुना चैव
> > रुद्रेण च विशेषतः ॥ २ ॥ इंद्रादिलोकपारैश्च सूर्याद्यैर्नवभिर्ग्रहैः ।
> > विश्वामित्रवसिष्ठाद्यैर्ब्रह्मविद्भिर्महर्षिभिः ॥ ३ ॥
> > श्वेतागस्त्यदधीचाद्यैरस्माभिश्च शिवाश्रितैः ।
> > नंदीश्वरमहाकालभृंगीशाद्यैर्गणेश्वरैः ॥ ४ ॥ पातालवासिभिर्दैत्यैः
> > शेषाद्यैश्च महोरगैः । सिद्धैर्यक्षैश्च गंधर्वै रक्षोभूतपिशाचकैः ॥ ५ ॥
> > **स्वंस्वं पदमनुप्राप्तं सर्वैरयमनुष्ठितः । अनेन विधिना सर्वे देवा
> > देवत्वमागताः ॥ ६ ॥ ब्रह्मा ब्रह्मत्वमापन्नो विष्णुर्विष्णुत्वमागतः ।
> > रुद्रो रुद्रत्वमापन्न इंद्रश्चेन्द्रत्वमागतः ॥ ७ ॥**
> >
> > ~ Śiva-Māhapurāṇa, 7.2.33.2-7
> >
> > 2-6. The rite (Shivarchana) is attended with the excellence of merits.
> > It has been performed by all the gods, particularly by Brahmā, Viṣṇu,
> > Rudra, Indra, the guardians of the quarters, the nine planets—sun-god
> > and others, by Viśvāmitra, Vasiṣṭha and other sages who know Brahman,
> > by Śveta, Agastya, Dadhīca and others, by us seeking refuge in Śiva,
> > by Nandīśvara, Mahākāla, Bhṛṅgīśa and other Gaṇeśvaras, by the Daityas
> > residing in the nether worlds, by Śeṣa and other serpents, by Siddhas,
> > Yakṣas, Gandharvas, Rākṣasas, Bhūtas, Piśācas and practically by every
> > one who has attained his respective position. It is by means of this
> > rite that the gods have attained their godhood.
> >
> > **7. Brahmā attained his Brahmāhood, Viṣṇu his Viṣṇuhood, Rudra his Rudrahood and Indra his Indrahood. It is by means of this rite that
> > Gaṇeśa attained his Gaṇeśahood.**
>
> ---
>
> ### From Brahmvaivarta Purana :
>
> > सर्वेश्वर्यं सर्वसिद्धिं मुक्ति मुक्ति हरेः पदम्। दैत्यः किंचिन्न
> > गृह्णाति प्रेरितः शुलपाणिना ।।
> >
> > ~ Brahmavaivartapurāṇa, Krishna Birth, 36.28
> >
> > **Siva offered him all the fortunes, the siddhis, the devotion, salvation and the Position of Hari,** but the demon did not accept
> > them.

---

### So why the Position of Brahma Vishnu Indra and other gods can be achieved , aren't they and their positions Eternal ? Because Brahma, Vishnu, Indra are in cycle of Death and their positions aren't eternal it's ever-changing.

---

> ### There are unlimited Brahmās, Viṣṇus, Rudras and other Devas in
> Unlimited Brahmandas, but Lord Śiva is only One
>
> > असंख्याताश्च कल्पाख्या असंख्याताः पितामहाः । हरयश्चाप्यसंख्याता एक एव
> > महेश्वरः ॥ कोटिकोट्ययुतान्यत्र ब्रह्माण्डानि मम प्रिये ।
> > जलबुद्बुदवद्देवि संजातानि तु लीलया ॥ तत्रतत्र चतुर्वक्त्रा ब्रह्माणो
> > हरयो भवाः । सृष्टाः प्रधानेन तदा लब्धा शंभोस्तु संनिधिः ॥
> >
> > ~  ā, ...-
> >
> > **Īśvara said to Īśvari : Innumerable are those (periods) called Kalpa. The Pitāmahas (Brahmās) are innumerable and Haris too are
> > innumerable. But Maheśvara is one and only one.**
> >
> > Like formations of bubbles in water, O my beloved, crores and ten
> > thousand crores of Brahmāṇḍas (Cosmic Eggs) issue forth from me in my
> > sport.
> >
> > **In different Brahmāṇḍas (Cosmic Eggs), four-faced Brahmās, Narayanas and Bhavas are created by the Pradhāna (Māyā). Then the
> > proximity to
> > Śaṃbhu was obtained.**
>
> ---
>
> ### Vishnu's age = four inhalings of Mahesha
>
> > ब्रह्माधिकबलो विष्णुरायुषि ब्रह्मणोऽधिकः ॥  ब्रह्मांडमालाभरणे महेशस्य
> > ममैव तु । चतुर्निःश्वासमात्रेण विष्णोरायुरुदाहृतम् ॥
> >
> > ~  ,  ,. -
> >
> > **Viṣṇu has more power than Brahma, and has also longer life than Brahmā in sustaining the row of ‘Brahmā’s eggs’. The life of Viṣṇu is
> > said to be of the measure of four inhalings of Maheśa and me.**
>
> ---
>
> ### Lord Shiva said to Mata Parvati that Brahma and Vishnu are also in
> Birth and Death Cycle
>
> > ममैव निमिषार्द्धेन सहस्राणि चतुर्द्दश । विनश्यंति ततो विष्णोरसंख्याताः
> > पितामहाः ॥
> >
> > ~  ā-āṇ,  ...
> >
> > **Lord Shiva said : Along with half of a Nimiṣa pertaining to me, fourteen thousand Viṣṇus and unlimited number of Pitamahas (Brahmas)
> > die .**
>
> ---
>
> ### Mata Parvati asked Lord Shiva about his Garland of Skulls, Then Lord
> Shiva replied that his Garland is made with the Skulls of thousands of
> Narayanas and ten thousands of Brahmas.
>
> > देव्युवाच । यदि त्वं च महादेवो मुण्डमाला कथं कृता । अनादि निधनो धाता
> > सृष्टिसंहारकारकः ॥ ततो विहस्य देवेशः शंकरो वाक्यमब्रवीत् ।
> > अनेकमुण्डकोटीभिर्या मे माला विराजते ॥  नारायण सहस्राणां
> > ब्रह्मणामयुतस्य च ॥ कृता शिरःकरोटीभिरनादिनिधना ततः ॥ अन्यो विष्णुश्च
> > भवति अन्यो ब्रह्मा भवत्यपि । कल्पे कल्पे मया सृष्टः कल्पे विष्णुः
> > प्रजापतिः ॥
> >
> > ~  , ...-
> >
> > - If you are the great Lord, the creator without
> > beginning and end, the cause of creation and annihilation, how is it
> > that a garland of skulls has been worn (by you)?
> >
> > Thereupon, Śaṅkara, the Lord of Devas, laughed and spoke these words:
> > “**This garland of mine that shines with many crores of skulls has been
> > made out of skulls of thousands of Nārāyaṇas and ten thousand Brahmās.**
> > Therefore, it is devoid of beginning and end.
> >
> > **A new Viṣṇu is born in every Kalpa. So also a new Brahmā. In every
> > Kalpa, Viṣṇu and Prajāpati are created by me.**
>
> ---
>
> ### In Matsya Purana, Narada Muni said that Brahma, Vishnu and all other
> gods are just playthings of Lord Shiva and they are all subject of
> Birth and Death cycle.
>
> > ब्रह्मविष्णिवन्द्रमुनयो जन्ममृत्युजरार्दिताः। तस्यैते परमेशस्य सर्वे
> > क्रीडनका गिरे।॥ १७९॥ आस्ते ब्रह्मा तदिच्छातः सम्भूतो भुवनप्रभुः ।
> > विष्णुर्युगे युगे जातो नानाजातिर्महातनुः ।। १८०॥ मन्यसे मायया जातं
> > विष्णुं चापि युगे युगे। आत्मनो न विनाशोऽस्मि स्थावरान्तेऽपि भूधर ।। १८
> > १॥
> >
> > ~ Matsya Purāņam, 154.179-181
> >
> > He is the refuge of all, the Immutable and the God. **Brahmā, Vişņu,
> > Indra and Muni are all subject to the cycle of birth, death and old
> > age.**
>
> ---
>
> ### There are unlimited number of Brahma, Vishnu, Indra and Other Gods but
> Maheśvara is only One, the Supreme Lord.
>
> > असंख्याताश्च संक्षेपात् प्रधानादन्वधिष्ठितात्। असंख्याताश्च कल्पाख्या
> > ह्यसंख्याताः पितामहाः ॥ हरयञ्चाप्यसंख्यातास्त्वेक एव महेश्वरः ।
> >
> > ~ Liṅga Mahāpurāṅam, 1.4.54-55
> >
> > Such creations through the agency Pradhana are innumerable. **The kalpas
> > together with Brahmas and Vişnus, are innumerable. But lord Siva is
> > only one.**
>
> ---
>
> ### In Soundrya Lahari Adi Shankaracharya described the Eternity of
> Shivashakti (Brahma Vishnu and all other gods dies at the Time of
> Mahapralaya) :
>
> > विरिञ्चिः पञ्चत्वं व्रजति हरिराप्नोति विरतिं विनाशं कीनाशो भजति  धनदो
> > याति निधनम्। वितन्द्री माहोन्द्री विततिरपि संमीलितदृशा
> > महासंहारेऽस्मिन् विहरति सति त्वत्पतिरसौ॥
> >
> > ~Soundarya Lahari(Adi Shankaracarya), Sloka 26
> >
> > **Brahma eventually comes to the end of his life; Vishnu also meets his
> > end eventually;** Yama, the lord of death   is destroyed; Kubera, the
> > lord of wealth is also destroyed; Indra and his courtiers (who are not
> > subject to fatigue or sleepiness) also finally close their eyes. **Oh!
> > the most chaste one, even during the time of destruction, the total
> > dissolution (the maha-pralaya kaala)! O Sathi, chaste Consort of
> > Shiva, this Sadaa-Siva, your husband, dances, the samhaara taandava
> > being witnessed by you alone.**
>
> ---
>
> ### Words of Basavanna :
>
> > -జర నందే ఎందరి కురియన ಬಾಯಲ್ಲಿ ಬಾಲ ಹುಳುಗಳು ? ಹತ್ತು ಪ್ರಳಯ | ಬ್ರಹ್ಮಂಗನಂತ ಪ್ರಳಯ ಹರಿಗೆ ಹರೆಂಗೆ ಪ್ರಳಯುವುಂಟೆಂಬುದ ಬಲ್ಲರೆ ನೀವು ಹೇಳಿರಿ !
> > ಪ್ರಳಯ,
> > ಅಂದಂದಿಗೆ ! ಹಳೆಯ ಕೂಡಲ ಸಂಗಮದೇವ !!
> >
> > Meaning: **The person who says Hara and Hari are equal will have insects
> > in their mouth, Hari has 10 deaths Bramha has infinite deaths, But
> > Kudalasangamadeva has no deaths (kalathita).** By, Basavanna
>
> > -೫೩೯ ಒಬ್ಬ ಕೆಂಚನೊಬ್ಬ ಕರಿಕನೊಬ್ಬ ಶುದ್ಧ ಧವಳಿತನೆಂತಯ್ಯಾ ಲಿಂಗವೇ ? ಒಬ್ಬರಿಗೊಬ್ಬರು ಘನವೆಂಬರು; ಅದೆಂತಯ್ಯಾ ? ಒಬ್ಬರಿಗೊಬ್ಬರು ಹಿರಿದೆಂಬರು; ಎಂತಯ್ಯಾ
> > ? ಬ್ರಹ್ಮಪ್ರಳಯ, ವಿಷ್ಣುಮರಣ ಉಂಟು, ನಮ್ಮ ಕೂಡಲ ಸಂಗಂಗಿಲ !
> >
> > One is of a dark hue (vishnu) Another one is of a reddish
> > hue (bramha). Both fighting about each other's greatness. **Vishnu has
> > his death and Bramha also has a end but pure white hued personality
> > Mrityunjaya mahadeva is Supreme and is free from Janma, Mrityu and
> > Jara.**
> >
> > By, Basavanna

---

[image]

### ॥ सर्वं शिवमयं जगत् ॥

Answer (score 2):

Mahābhārat — Anūśāsan Parva- Chapter —18 , Verse-64.:

> Vasudeva said., "...If Rudra be gratified with a person, he can confer upon him the states of eIther Brahma or of Kesava or of Sakra with all the deities under him, or the sovereignty of the three worlds. Those men, O sire, who worship Bhava even mentally, succeed in freeing themselves from all sins and attain to a residence in heaven with all the gods..."

Atharvashika Upanishad 2:1.:

> “The pranava (the sound of Om) makes all the souls to bow before it. It is the one and only one which has to be meditated upon as the four Vedas and the birth place of all devas. One who meditates like that goes away from all sorrows and fears and gets the power to protect all others who approach him. It is because of this meditation only that Lord Vishnu who is spread every where, wins over all others. It is because Lord Brahma controlled all his organs and meditated upon it, he attained the position of the creator. Even Lord Vishnu , parks his mind in the sound (Om) of the place of Paramathma (ultimate soul) and meditates upon Îsâna. , who is most proper to be worshipped. All this is only proper in case of Îsâna. ”.

Svetasvatara Upanishad. 3.4.:

> He, the omniscient Rudra, the Creator of the Gods and the Bestower of their powers and positions, the Support of the universe, He who, in the beginning, gave birth to Hiranyagarbha -may He endow us with clear intellect!

Sathapatha Brahmana 13:6:1:1.:

> "Purusha Narayana desired, 'Would that I overpassed all beings ! would that I alone were everything- here (this universe) !' He beheld this 'five days' sacrificial performance, the Purushamedha and took it and performed offering therewith ; and having performed offering therewith, he overpassed all beings, and became everything here. And, verily, he who, knowing this, performs the Purushamedha, or who even knows this, overpasses all beings, and becomes everything here."

Taittiriya Aranyaka 10:24:1.:

> "Lord Rudra is the (Veda) Purusha."

Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.1.5.22-23.:

> May we know the Supreme Person (Purusha) and for the attainment of His Knowledge may we meditate upon Him, the thousand-eyed Great God (Mahadeva). May Rudra, the giver of Knowledge, impel us towards such meditation and keep us in it.
>
> May we know or realize that Supreme Person (Tat-Purusha). For that, may we meditate upon Mahadeva and to that meditation may Rudra impel us.

Mahabharata 7 : 172: verse No. 74,78.:

> By the grace of me (Rudra) you will become Nārāyaṇa with unending strength among the deities, humans and Gandharvas.
>
> “Through my grace, none shall ever be able to cause thee pain by the weapon of thunderbolt or with any object that is wet or dry, or with any mobile or immobile thing. Thou shalt be superior to myself if thou ever goest to battle against me.'”

MBH 13:14:10-11.:

> "The Krishna, due to his devotion to Supreme Lord Rudra, Has spread all over the universe (jagat vyaptham mahathmana viz became all pervasive Vishnu), Oh Bharatha, Oh king of kings, After making Lord Shiva pleased by his penance in Bhadrinath, He has attained the state of being more dear, Than all the worlds and all aspects of knowledge."

MBH 13:14:13.:

> “In every new Yuga has Krishna (by such penances) gratified Mahadeva. In every Yuga has Mahadeva been gratified with the great devotion of the high-souled Krishna“.

Sūta Saṃhitā ŚivaMahātmya Khaṃḍa —3:14.:

> Nandi to Visnu:
>
> By a smallest part of Śiva's grace you have attained this Viṣṇu position not otherwise.

Skanda Purāṇam — Kaśi Khaṅda, 1st section —(13:9).:

> Putātmā said: 9. O Great lord, O Lord of the Devas, O bestower of freedom from fear unto the Devas, O bestower of the positions to all the Devas including Brahmā, Nārāyaṇa, Indra and others!

Parāśar Ūpa Purāṇam — Chapter-16.:

> Viṣṇu attains Viṣṇu Position, Bramhā attains Bramhā Position and Indra attains Indra's Position by doing Śiva Bhakti.,

Shiva Purana 7.2.33.7.:

> kings, Siddhas, Yakṣas and Gandharvas, Rākṣasas, Bhūtas and Pisacas, besides other acheived their respective positions by adoring Śiva. All the gods achieved god-hoods, with the same process. Brahma achieved Brahmattva, Visņu achieved the position of Vişņu, Rudra got Rudratva, and Indra got the position of Indra. Gaṇeśa was bestowed Gaṇeśahood with the same process. Bathing Siva-linga with the white sandal paste it should be adored with the white lotus flowers. The salutation should be offered thereafter.

Śrī śivānanda Laharī ||18.:

> It means Viṣṇu, Bramhā , Indra all attain their positions by mere grace of Śiva and they always worship Śiva.

Skanda Purana/Khanda. 8 (Ambika Khanda), Chapter 21.:

> 13-14. Pleased with Nandi’s devotion, Lord Shiva offers him boons: Ask whether you want Brahmatva, Vishnutva, Indratva, or something else – Aditya or Rudra.
>
> 46-48. Nandi replied: I don’t want Brahmatva Vishnutva Indratva, I want to be near you as one of your servants. Please grant me this boons.

Skanda Purana 5:1:38.:

> Sanatkumāra said:
>
> Even as a hundred years elapsed while he was eulogizing thus, Lord Śaṅkara, the trident-bearing Lord, with a bull as his emblem, was pleased and he spoke thus:
>
> “Son, welfare unto you. I am pleased with you. Now you have become free from impurities. I shall give you divine vision. Look at me without mental affliction.
>
> O excellent Dānava, tell me whatever benefit has been desired mentally by you; I shall grant you.”
>
> The Dānava Andhaka said:
>
> The position of Brahmā, Viṣṇu or Indra is characterized by coming and going (i.e. impermanence). All this is known to me. I do not desire it at all.
>
> O Lord of Devas, if you are pleased, grant me Gāṇapatya—lordship of the Gaṇas. That is something especially pure and everlasting.

~ Vachana 291 (Basava Samiti Ed.).:

> The position of Brahma, I do not want
>
> The postion of Vishnu, I do not want
>
> The postion of Rudra, I do not want
>
> I don't want any other postion Koodalasangamadeva
>
> Grant me the great postion
>
> Of being knowingly at the feet of Your (Shiva's) Sharanas.

Kena Upanishad 4.1-3.:

> Uma said: "It was Brahman. In the victory that was Brahman's you were reveling in joy". Then alone did Indra know for certain that It was Brahman. [1]
>
> Therefore, these gods viz. Agni, Vayu and Indra excelled other gods, for they touched Brahman who stood very close and indeed knew first that It was Brahman. [2]
>
> Therefore is Indra more excellent than the other gods, for he touched Brahman (Yaksha/Rudra) who stood very close and indeed knew first that It was Brahman. [3]

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Hello brother..

Comment: Hey bro........

Comment: Are you on telegram  ?

Comment: Yes, i have it but I don't use it regularly.

Comment: I have a group on telegram for Shiva devotees.  Love to see you there.  Will you come ?

Comment: Sure, why not. Give me the link..

Comment: https://t.me/shaivamsadavijayate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150216/discussion-between-rudrasadashiva108-and-sri-shiva-charanam-dsa-vishnu).

Answer (score 2):

The **question title asks** - "Can/Does bhagvaan Mahadev Shiv ji bestow other God's 'position' on jiva"?

### Answer =

1. **Yes**. But only and exclusively as per the strict Shaiv exclusive worldview and scriptures only.
2. **No**. But non-Shaiv scriptures and sampraday like shakt, vaishnav, hiranyagarbh, saur, ganapatis, etc. will hugely disagree that shiv ji can bestow any position on any jiva and especially not that of the respective sects' supreme gods (since to start with they are not a "position" or "post/pad" like vacancy to be filled). So in this case, the answer is a resounding and unfalsifiable NO .

I'm providing a short passage from one of the most authoritative scripture within the Shakt sampraday, which is also a Puranam - **the Devi Bhagvat Puran**.

> Navam Skandh  >> sapta-vimsho adhyaya
>
> धर्मराज उवाच
>
> कर्मणा जायते जन्तुः कर्मणैव प्रलीयते । सुखं दुःखं भयं शोकः कर्मणैव
> प्रणीयते ॥ १७ ॥ कर्मणेन्द्रो भवेज्जीवो ब्रह्मपुत्रः स्वकर्मणा ।
> **स्वकर्मणा हरेर्दासो जन्मादिरहितो भवेत्** ॥ १८ ॥ स्वकर्मणा
> सर्वसिद्धिममरत्वं लभेद्‌ ध्रुवम् । **लभेत् स्व कर्मणा विष्णोः
> सालोक्यादिचतुष्टयम्** ॥ १९ ॥ सुरत्वं च मनुत्वं च राजेन्द्रत्वं लभेन्नरः
> । **कर्मणा च शिवत्वं च गणेशत्वं तथैव च** ॥ २० ॥ कर्मणा च मुनीन्द्रत्वं
> तपस्वित्वं स्वकर्मणा । स्वकर्मणा क्षत्रियत्वं वैश्यत्वं च स्वकर्मणा ॥
> २१ ॥ कर्मणैव च म्लेच्छत्वं लभते नात्र संशयः । स्वकर्मणा जङ्‌गमत्वं
> शैलत्वं च स्वकर्मणा ॥ २२ ॥ कर्मणा राक्षसत्वं च किन्नरत्वं स्वकर्मणा ।
> कर्मणैवाधिपत्यं च वृक्षत्वं च स्वकर्मणा ॥ २३ ॥ कर्मणैव पशुत्वं च
> वनजीवी स्वकर्मणा । कर्मणा क्षुद्रजन्तुत्वं कृमित्वं च स्वकर्मणा ॥ २४ ॥
> दैतेयत्वं दानवत्वमसुरत्वं स्वकर्मणा । इत्येतदुक्त्वा सावित्रीं विरराम
> स वै यमः ॥ २५ ॥

**Here below is the original Gita Press Gorakhpur's Devi Bhagvatam Puran's hindi interpretation of the above sanskrit shloks**

> प्राणी कर्म के अनुसार ही जन्म प्राप्त करता और कर्मानुसार ही मृत्यु को
> भी प्राप्त होता है। सुख- दुःख, भय और शोक भी कर्म से ही मिलते रहते हैं।
> जीव अपने कर्म के प्रभाव से इन्द्र हो सकता है, वह अपने कर्म से
> ब्रह्मपुत्र बन सकता है और **अपने कर्म के द्वारा वह श्री हरि विष्णु का
> दास बनकर जन्म-मरण के बन्धन से मुक्त हो जाता है**। मनुष्य अपने कर्म के
> प्रभाव से सम्पूर्ण सिद्धियाँ, अमरत्व और **भगवान् विष्णु के सालोक्य आदि
> चार प्रकार के मोक्ष-पद निश्चित रूप से प्राप्त कर सकता है** ॥ १७ – १९ ॥
>
> **मनुष्य को अपने कर्म के द्वारा देवता, मनु, राजेन्द्र, शिव तथा गणेश तक
> का पद सुलभ हो जाता है** । उसी प्रकार अपने कर्म के प्रभाव से ही मनुष्य
> श्रेष्ठ मुनि, तपस्वी ब्राह्मण, क्षत्रिय, वैश्य तथा म्लेच्छ बन जाता है;
> इसमें कोई सन्देह नहीं है। अपने कर्मानुसार ही प्राणी को जंगम, पर्वत,
> राक्षस, किन्नर, अधिपति, वृक्ष, पशु, वन के प्राणी, अत्यन्त सूक्ष्म
> जन्तु, कीट, दैत्य, दानव तथा असुर आदि योनियाँ प्राप्त होती हैं ।
> सावित्री से ऐसा कहकर वे यमराज चुप हो गये ॥ २० - २५॥

The English interpretation by Swami Vijnanananda is being provided for the benefit of all readers now -

> In the 27th Chapter within the Ninth Book of the Devi Bhagvat Puran,
>
> Dharmraj (the God of Death and the Netherworlds i.e.  Yamraj bhagvaan
> ji)  said -
>
> Every living animal is born by his Karma. He dies again through his
> life long Karma. It is his Karma alone that ordains pleasure, pain,
> fear, sorrows, etc. By Karma, this embodied soul here becomes Indra;
> by Karma he can become a Brahmā’s son. What more than this that Jīva,
> **by his Karma, can be in Hari’s service and be free from birth and
> death**! By one’s own Karma all sorts of Siddhis and immortality can be
> obtained; **the four blessed regions as Viṣṇu’s Sālokya, etc., also can
> be obtained by Karma**.
>
> What more than this that **by Karma, a being
> becomes divine, human, or a King, or Śiva or Ganeśa** ! The state of
> Munīndra, asceticism, Kṣattriyahood, Vaiśyahood, Mlechahood, moving
> things, stones, Rākṣasahood, Kinnaras, Kingship, becoming trees,
> beasts, forest animals, inferior animals, worms, Daityas, Dānavas,
> Asuras, all are fashioned and wrought by Karma and Karma alone. O
> Nārada! Thus speaking, Yama remained silent.

**So in short,**
As per the Devi Bhagvat purana, it is ONLY THROUGH one's own Karma that a jeevaatmaa can become a deva, asura, naga, kinnar, brahmin, shudr, etc. And through right karma jeevaatmaa can obtain the position of devraj Indra ji, bhagwaan Shiv ji and bhagwaan Ganesh ji also.

Also through appropriate karm, the jeevaatmaa can obtain the service of Shri Hari Vishnu Bhagwaan ji and also the four types of exclusive Moksha that Shri Narayan Vishnu ji provide are obtained through appropriate karm and not otherwise.

### Hence the karm or Karma that a jeevaatmaa performs is responsible for obtaining anything in the previous or present or any future births including the "position of any God or living entity".

Thus Karma is the Supreme and the Only bestower of any fruits, curse, boons, punishments and even the position of any God or goddess, etc., as Shri Goswaami Tulsidaas ji writes in the doha - **कर्म प्रधान विश्व रचि राखा, जो जस करहि सो तसि फल चाखा**  i.e. The existence is primarily governed by the Karma, which is supreme. As one sows so shall they reap.

## So to answer the titular question - the answer is NO.

Umapati bhagwaan Shivji does not and CANNOT provide/bestow upon any jeeva, any so called "position or post" of any god including Vishnu ji (Narayan, Krishna, Ram, etc) and Chaturmukh Brahmaa ji.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Bhagavana Shiva as Well as Devi can grant the positions of Brahma as well As Vishnu.

### Sri Varaha Puranam Chapter 213

> **उवाच च वचः साक्षात्तमृषिं वरदः प्रभुः ।। वरान्वृणीष्व विप्रेन्द्र यानिच्छसि महामुने ।। ५१ ।। तांस्ते सर्वान्प्रयच्छामि दुर्ल्लभानपि
> मारिष ।। प्रभुत्वममरत्वं वा शक्रत्वमपि वा प्रभो ।। ५२ ।। ब्रह्मत्वं
> लोकपालत्वमपवर्गमथापि वा ।। अथाष्टगुणमैश्वर्यं गाणपत्यमथापि वा ।। ५३
> ।।**
>
> Shiva says to Nandi-
>
> O great sage, seek from me whatever boons you wish.  I shall grant you
> all of them, even if they are such as are not  normally granted.
>
> Tell me soon what you desire, whether it is lordship,  the status of Devas, Indra or Brahma, the position of the guardian  deities,
> liberation, eight-fold power or leadership of Ganas.

Btw, It's patently false to claim that merely Saiva Scriptures Speak of Brahma, Visnu adi trimurtis as positions attainable by Karma or the Kripa of Shiva or Devi.
Citing from the Devi Bhagavata itself-

### Devi Bhagavata Purana Book 11 Chapter 18

> **श्रीनारायण उवाच मल्लिकामालतीपुष्पैरष्टगन्धेन लोलितैः ॥ २५ ॥ कोटिसङ्‌ख्यैः पूजया तु जायते स चतुर्मुखः । दशकोटिभिरप्येवं तैरेव
> कुसुमैर्मुने ॥ २६ ॥ विष्णुत्वं लभते मर्त्यो यत्सुरेष्वपि दुर्लभम् ।
> विष्णुनैतद्‌व्रतं पूर्वं कृतं स्वपदलब्धये ॥ २७ ॥ शतकोटिभिरप्येवं
> सूत्रात्मत्वं व्रजेद्‌ध्रुवम् । व्रतमेतत्पुरा सम्यक्कृतं भक्त्या
> प्रयत्‍नतः ॥ २८ ॥**
>
> Nārāyaṇa said- If any devotee worships Devī with ten millions of
> entire fresh green Kuṇḍa flowers, with eight scents, he gets surely
> the Prajāpatihood. **The worship of the Devī with ten millions of
> Mallikā and Mālatī flowers besmeared with eight scents makes a man the
> four faced (Brahmā); and one hundred millions of such flowers will
> make the devotee a Viṣṇu. In days of yore, Viṣṇu worshipped the Devī
> in the aforesaid way and so got His Viṣṇuhood.**